# asp.net suppress internet explorer error dialog box

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, error-handling

This is only supposed to work on IE 8.0

On my asp.net page, I press the save button and it goes through some server side code. Upon an error on server side code, on the web page, I get Internet Explorer Error dialog titled "Errors on this webpage might cause it to work incorrectly". I know exactly what is causing this error on server side.

I do not have try catch handling in my webpages. I bubble up all my errors to Global.asax and log them in the event Application_Error.

So.. my questions are

**1. How do I suppress this pop up Internet Explorer Error dialog?**

**2. How do I In Application_Error in Global.asax, redirect to another asp.net page called GenericErrPage.aspx where I display user friendly custom text message.**

Please help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: a few questions, what version of IE are you using? Do you get this message in other browsers? Is the site running locally in debug mode or is this being deployed and the error generating from a deployed site? From the image you have covered the content of the error. Is the error a scripting event (client side) or is this a server side event and the stack trace is showing in the window? Can you provide some info to on when the message is getting generated. You tagged this question with ajax, is an AJAX function calling a serverside method triggering this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all I had to do was to add the following line in system.web section in web.config and it stopped the dialog box from popping up. Also, I was able to log the err in Application_Error in Global.asax file.

```
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/CustomError.aspx" mode="On" />
```